# Execute shell script or command on idle time

Tags: scripts, command-line, idle

I'm searching for the possibility to execute a shell script or command based on idle time in the bash shell.

As an example, if I'm in a SSH session to a server of mine and after X minutes of inactivity in the terminal, I want a command to start a desired program like `cmatrix`, and when I come back and press a key I will get back where I left.

Comment: You can check the load on cpu using `top`

Comment: Why not run your `cmatrix` or whatever all the time, but with a `nice --adjustment=17` low scheduling priority? See `man nice`. Then, when you do something interactive, it will have a normal (0) scheduling priority and take over.

Answer (score 9):

Apparently GNU screen has [screensaver capabilities](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/at-long-last-a-console-screensaver/) similar to what you're asking, if you put this in your `.screenrc`:

```
blankerprg cmatrix -ab -u2
idle 60 blanker
```

Comment: Is there no way to get it to run with the `-l` option too?

Comment: This only works with a `screen` session, no?

Comment: For noobs like me. You have to first run `screen -q` cmd. then you are in screen terminal :(