# How do I get cmatrix to turn on after a certain period of inactivity in console?

Tags: screensaver, console, cmatrix

I have got the console screensaver `cmatrix`, and I was wondering if there is anyway of getting it to turn on after a certain amount of inactivity in the console you are in?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
cmatrix:
  Installed: 1.2a-5build1
  Candidate: 1.2a-5build1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2a-5build1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Possibly useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/506501/run-script-on-system-idle, http://superuser.com/questions/638357/execute-a-command-if-linux-is-idle-for-5-minutes, and if you're on a console: http://askubuntu.com/questions/275919/execute-shell-script-or-command-on-idle-time

Comment: Toroidal: can you report back if that helped you so that @muru can convert this to an answer?

Answer (score 6):

cmatrix is really intended as a CLI tool. I'm not sure you can easily turn it into a screensaver.

An alternate option it to install:

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver-gl
```

and then select:  GLmatrix

reference1:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2052562
reference2:  if you're running gnome/unity might be needed.  [How can I change or install screensavers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64086/how-can-i-change-or-install-screensavers)