# Looking for a 'screensaver' (animated framebuffer graphics, not just blanking) on a X-less system for the console

Tags: screensaver

I have a small Ubuntu 23.04 system without X11 or Wayland (server edition) where I want an oldschool screensaver in the text console.

Is there *any* program in the Ubuntu distribution which can achieve this? I know of the possibility to have a slideshow of pictures with `fbi`, `feh` or `fim`, but I'm looking more for starfield simulation, fireworks or generally any `xsceensaver`-like visuals.

If this is not available, I would settle for a guide to blank the console and unblank on a key press.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `tmux`, you can set a command to run after some time. A popular choice would be `cmatrix`, which emulates the digital rain of characters from the Matrix movies.

Set the following in your `tmux` config:

```
set -g lock-after-time 5
set -g lock-command "cmatrix; vlock"
```

This means that after 5 minutes of inactivity, the screensaver starts, first by running the `cmatrix` command, and then followed by the `vlock` command, which prompts for your password.

It goes without saying that you need to install both `cmatrix` and `vlock` first:

```
sudo apt install cmatrix vlock
```

You could also drop `cmatrix` entirely, and go directly to `vlock`, which clears the screen and prompts for password.

Also [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699579/ascii-screensaver-for-the-command-line-or-a-tui) for suggestions for other ASCII screensaver programs.

Comment: I need to test it, but wouldn't `vlock` automatically clear also `cmatrix` output? I tried with `vlock` already, but it did put out a static text which was not desirable.

Comment: No, `vlock` does not run until `cmatrix` have exited - it works as expected. You can also skip `vlock` if you don't need to lock the terminal.

Comment: Although I forgot to specifically ask for it, do you have any link to a non-ASCII (framebuffer) screensaver? Since modern consoles are able to put out graphics, it would be nice to use this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any such screensaver application.